# Can private data be encrypted and stored safely in public?

Tags: aes

Given that AES-256 is reasonably strong encryption, can private data (for example Bitcoin private keys) be sufficiently encrypted and stored safely in public places (for example a public github repository)?

Comment: **Yes** (assuming you do not store your AES-256 encryption keys in a public place too).

Comment: I think a good example is steganography.  You can post a container file somewhere with encrypted data embedded in the media, and there's a chance no one will notice.  Most big-name sites (Facebook, Google, etc.) block uploading stego'd files, though.  This isn't AES, of course, but it is one way to try what you're asking.

Comment: Yes you can do it but it is risky as much in the key handling could go wrong. So while you can do it you should probably not do it with your most valuable bitcoin valet which contains your pension fund.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is: *if and only if* the key is never compromised and the algorithm is never severely broken.

To inject some realism into this question, one real-life event that's worth knowing is how Wikileaks' encrypted file of USA diplomatic cables got compromised.  [Bruce Schneier had a good summary at the time](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/09/unredacted_us_d.html) (it's not a primary source, but he links such sources).  But the basic idea is:

1. Wikileaks encrypts a file with lots of sensitive information, using password-based encryption.
2. Wikileaks shares the file and password with a journalist.
3. Wikileaks posts the encrypted file into Bittorrent as a backup/survival measure.
4. The journalist, who is not technically savvy at all, writes a book and uses the password as a chapter title.
5. Observers manage to put two and two together, download the torrent, and decrypt it with the password from the book.

How does this address your question?  Well, if the file had not been uploaded to a public system like Bittorrent, the damage from the exposure of the password would have been much smaller.  So publicizing a ciphertext widely certainly carries additional risks.

That's not a yes/no answer to your scenario, because there isn't one.  Restricting the circulation of the ciphertext is always safer, but this is really a risk vs. convenience tradeoff where you might reasonably opt for convenience, depending on the application.

Answer (score 4):

The [Defense in depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_(computing)) security model is based on multi layers of security.

The assumption is that one should have several security layers, so if a few layers will break, the rest of the layers will hold until one will fix the broken layers.

Placing sensitive private date (in your example *Bitcoin private keys*) in public using only one layer of security (e.g. AES-256 encryption) conflict with the *Defense in depth* security model, and it is not recommended.

Comment: Defense in depth is not very useful for encrypted data on a public server: You can't fix any of the layers afterwards - the encrypted data is public with the layers you put in place when publishing it / sending it to the public server.

Comment: @tylo - I tried to say that , based on the *defense of depth* model, it is not recommended to place sensitive data on a public server. It is better to have several defenses (e.g. encryption of the sensitive data AND placing it in a private/secure server)

Comment: Then your answer doesn't adress the question, does it? The question was explicitly about how to encrypt so that you can store them on a public server. But of course you're right: Storing credentials for any kind of authentication (including private keys) in public is a bad idea and can weaken security a lot.